# Line graph not displayed with plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly, timeserieschart

My final aim is to create 2 time series line graphs on the same plot, with the one being static and the other being animated (the former refers to the actual data and the latter on my model's fitted values). I am trying to accomplish that with plotly, however I am completely new and have crossed difficulties.

In order to get familiar with plotly first before attempting the above I initially tried to create just one animated graph on a plot. However I cannot even make that ostensibly simple script work. When running the below no graph is displayed on my plot area, like there are no data. My script is created based on following link: https://plot.ly/r/cumulative-animations/

```
plot_ly(data
        , x=~data$RequCreatedFull_Date
        , y=~data$fitted_TotalRequ_Qnt_pm
        , name="Fitted"
        , type='scatter'
        , mode = "lines"
        , line = list(color = "rgb(255,128,0)")
        , frame = ~data$RequCreatedFull_Date
        , line = list(simplyfy = F)) %>%
layout(title="name"
       , xaxis = list(range = 
                           c(as.numeric(min(data$RequCreatedFull_Date))*1000                              
                           ,as.numeric(max(data$RequCreatedFull_Date))*1000)
                      , type = "date"
                      , title = "Requisition Date"
                      , zeroline = F)
       , yaxis = list(title="Total Requisition Qnts"
                      , range = c(1000,30000)
                      , zeroline = F)) %>%
  animation_opts(frame = 100,
                 transition = 0,
                 redraw=FALSE) %>%
  animation_button(x = 1, xanchor = "right", y = 0, yanchor = "bottom")
```

`data` is a 53 obs, 4 variables (dates, actuals, fits, index) data frame.

When 'Play' button for animation is clicked and while the animation's frames proceed, when hovering on the plot area the data points' tooltips are displayed for a moment, however no graph is displayed.

Thank you in advance for all your assistance, hope I provided you with sufficient info.

Comment: Could you share just a sample of your data ? And do you get any error messages ?

Comment: I did not get any error message, the plot area was displayed correctly and the animation slider was running normally. In any case, I found my error (check answer below). Thanks though

Comment: fantastic! would be helpful if you show the code changes you made in your answer below to get it working

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @RK1. Please check my edited final answer.

Answer (score 1):

I mistakenly took *part* of the script the below link for the animated plotting (https://plot.ly/r/cumulative-animations/). The problem is that I did not modify the to-be-framed variable (variable to be used in `frame` parameter of `plot_ly` function) before using it.

Therefore, in order for the plot to work properly I should: 1. define `accumulate_by` function, 2. use it with the to-be-framed variable as input, 3. the output column produced from step 2 will be the value for the frame parameter of 'plot_ly' function.

Initial working data frame is `data2`, with columns `RequCreatedFull-Date(as POSIXct), Requs_Qnt_pm(as num), Type(as Factor), date(as num)` where
 `date=(year(RequCreatedFull_Date)+(month(RequCreatedFull_Date)-1)/12)`.

Please refer to working script below:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

#step 1: function definition
accumulate_by <- function(dat, var) {
  var <- lazyeval::f_eval(var, dat)
  lvls <- plotly:::getLevels(var)
  dats <- lapply(seq_along(lvls), function(x) {
   cbind(dat[var %in% lvls[seq(1, x)], ], frame = lvls[[x]])
  })
  dplyr::bind_rows(dats)
}

#step 2: creation of to-be-used for framing variable
data2mod <- data2 %>%
  accumulate_by(~date)


#graph creation
my_graph<-data2mod %>%
             plot_ly(
               x = ~date, 
               y = ~Requs_Qnt_pm,
               split = ~Type,
               frame = ~frame, #step 3, to be frame variable insertion
               type = 'scatter',
               mode = 'lines', 
               line = list(simplyfy = F)
            ) %>% 
             layout(
                xaxis = list(
                  title = "x axis title",
                  zeroline = F
               ),
                yaxis = list(
                  title = "y axis title",
                  zeroline = F
               )
            ) %>% 
            animation_opts(
              frame = 100, 
              transition = 0, 
              redraw = FALSE
            ) %>%
            animation_slider(
              hide = T
            ) %>%
            animation_button(
               x = 1, xanchor = "right", y = 0, yanchor = "bottom"
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

In xaxis and in yaxis showline=TRUE